# Unity android app startup time takes forever

Tags: unity-game-engine, optimization, zenject

My game's loading time is taking forever and it keeps getting longer by the time of adding new features.
I am using Zenject as the DI framework and the backbone of my game's architecture.
I realized that the moment when the Project Context is getting instantiated, the spike occurs.
After profiling, I came up with this:

[image]

It seems something related to loading things into memory is taking a long time.
On my device, Xiaomi mi 11 lite, it takes about 8 seconds. (the app freezes and does not respond to the input).
On a lower-end device like Galaxy A7, it takes about 25 seconds and it feels like the game is broken...